# How to get Element's Style value assigned from a Class

Tags: javascript, dom

If I defined a DIV as such

```
<div id='myDiv' style='display:none;'>inner stuff</div>
```

I can check it's current display value as such

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display;
```

And this returns a string == 'none'.

But, if I set my display style via a class the above statement returns a string of length zero.

```
<style>
    .myDivStyle {display:none;}
</style>
<div id='myDiv' class='myDivStyle'>inner stuff</div>
<script>
    var x = document.getElementByID('myDiv').style.display == ''; // returns true
</script>
```

Indeed the DIV is hidden in both cases, but in the latter case, how do I test that it is hidden (e.g. display=none) from javascript code?

Comment: I'm quite curious to understand what you're trying to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getComputedStyle` to get the styles used on an element and not just on the style property.

```js
var styles = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('myDiv'));
var display = styles.getPropertyValue('display')
console.log(display);
```

```css
.myDivStyle {display:none;}
```

```html
<div id='myDiv' class='myDivStyle'>inner stuff</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get the CSS properties of the element and [`CSSStyleDeclaration.getPropertyValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue) to get the value of the `display` property:

```html
<style>
    .myDivStyle {display:none;}
</style>
<div id='myDiv' class='myDivStyle'>inner stuff</div>
<script>
    var x = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('myDiv')).getPropertyValue("display")
    console.log(x)
</script>
```

Comment: Did not know about getComputedStyle()! Thanks. The second answer here is also the same and correct. But apparently I can only choose one to be the solution, so I guess the proper etiquette is to choose the first.

Comment: @JJJones_3860 I did not actually answer first ;) Musa answered 16 seconds before me.

Comment: Thank you Spectric. Very good of you. I have changed my vote.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use [`HTMLElement.hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/hidden) for handling the visibility of a div.
In order to get the status you can just access the property like this:

```
var x = document.getElementByID('myDiv').hidden
```

It will return a boolean value, indicating if the element is hidden or not.

Comment: Oddly enough. This is returning 'false' even when it is indeed hidden.,

Answer (score 0):

You can check by using the below code.

```
    if(document.querySelector('.myDivStyle').offsetParent == null)
   {
    // means element is hidden
   }
```

Or you can also check if that element has particular class which causes element to hide. e.g

```
document.querySelector('.hidden').classList.contains('myDivStyle')
```